# How to start service in a chroot independently of the host system?

Tags: services, arm, chroot, proc

I'm using `chroot` to create ARM Ubuntu installation from Ubuntu Core image. If I mount `/proc` and `/sys` all started services intercept with host system (trying to restart dbus is the worst thing it have yet tried). Currently I'm trying to work with only `/dev` mounted to chroot. This way `service` refuses to start jobs:

```
# service resolvconf start
start: Job failed to start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `/sys` was the problem. It worked with only `/dev` and `/proc` mounted.